# how to change the text inside a markerclusters icon?

Tags: google-maps-api-3

reference : http://code.google.com/p/google-maps-utility-library-v3/source/browse/trunk/markerclusterer/src/markerclusterer.js?r=110

on line 915 I am trying

```
this.div_.innerHTML = sums.text + "some additional info";
```

but it doesnt reflect the additional text?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried doing what you showed, changing the innerHTML, on version 2.0.9 of the clusterer. (line 244). It adds the static text to the cluster icon.

http://google-maps-utility-library-v3.googlecode.com/svn/tags/markerclustererplus/2.0.9/src/markerclusterer.js